# Store file in Firebase Storage using Cloud Functions REST API request

Tags: node.js, rest, firebase, firebase-storage

How do I store a file through a POST (form-data) HTTP REST request in **[Firebase Cloud Functions](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxk8TjhsPVAhXEalAKHXMqBiMQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Ffunctions%2F&usg=AFQjCNFdWm1QGO5vqjgc-GQ9UjC_XotMlQ)** so I can handle in the cloud after the REST request and then store in a bucket linked to my project.

For example is very easy to access but storage is not, I've tried to use **[multiparty](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjntXQhsPVAhWFZlAKHWXwD1AQFgg4MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpillarjs%2Fmultiparty&usg=AFQjCNE6dLDs7oKOb7EcdWKkC8rEYdLZ4Q)** and **[busboy](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-1erUhsPVAhXKIlAKHb3NCWsQFghmMAk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.npmjs.com%2Fpackage%2Fbusboy&usg=AFQjCNFA-6mwMpaCpZe24Y33wGEuncUgVw)** NodeJS libs but the problem still in that Im not able to save it in [**Firebase Storage**](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwisnayGh8PVAhWPmLQKHUbQBXAQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fstorage%2F&usg=AFQjCNHO0L8r0I86mMJ_kU4B1G63M3fKRg).

```
    var busboy = new Busboy({
        headers: req.headers
    });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        file.on('data', function(data) {
            // const object = data;
            // const fileBucket = object.bucket;
            // const bucket = gcs.bucket(filename);
            // const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
            console.log(data);
        });
        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
        });
    });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('Done parsing form!');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            Connection: 'close'
        });
        res.end();
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I finish doing this solution and works fine

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
    var files = 0, finished = false;
    busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
        ++files;
        var path = temp.writeFileSync(file);
        var fstream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        fstream.on('finish', function () {
            if (--files === 0) {
                var bucket = firebase.bucket();
                // Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
                bucket.upload(path+"",function (err, file) {

                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("Uploaded: " + path);
                        res.json({
                            uploaded: true,
                            created_at: new Date().getTime(),
                            filename: filename,
                            path: path,
                            mimeType: mimetype
                        });
                    }else{
                        console.error("err: " + err);
                        var error = new ErrorResponse(400);
                        error.errors+=err;
                        res.json(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        file.pipe(fstream);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to access fireabse/google cloud storage from a firebase function is to use the node js google cloud package for the service, in this case [@google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage).

Once its part of your functions' dependencies you simply start it up within your function js file:

`const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();`

Because the function runs in the google cloud environment there is no need to provide authentication info (unless storage and functions aren't part of the same Google Cloud/Firebase projects).

Comment: I have firebase storage running the problem is Im doing the request using an HTTP Post multipart, but I can't store it temporarily in the  function where I handle the post request with NodeJS using and then save it in google storage.